# How can I successfully run this script on a emulated terminal on Android?

Tags: installation, linux, terminal, scripts

### Background

I am trying to install Ubuntu onto my Acer Iconia A500 using VNC and this application called **Complete Linux Installer**. My tablet is rooted and I have found several sources saying they have achieved this on their tablet. It is Ubuntu 12.04, but since this is about doing this on the Android OS, it is off-topic on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

### Script

The script I am trying to run is as follows:

```
$ cd /sdcard/ubuntu $ su
# sh /data/data/com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid/files/bootscript.sh /sdcard/ubuntu/ubuntu.img
```

This is what it returns:

```
$ cd /sdcard/ubuntu $ su
# sh /data/data/com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid/files/bootscript.sh /sdcard/ubuntu/ubuntu.img
[: not found
dirname: not found
[[: not found
[: not found
[: not found
[: not found
[: not found
Checking loop device... [: not found
MISSING
Creating loop device... /data/data/com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid/files/bootscript.sh: /system/xbin/busybox: not found
[: not found
FAILED
Error: Unable to create loop device!
```

### Question

How am I able to install this correctly? I have `ubuntu.img` and `ubuntu.img.md5` in a folder named `ubuntu` in `/mnt/sdcard` which is the root of the system.

<sub>What is the `[:` part of `[: not found`? Is it just the script text?</sub>

Comment: Missing busybox? Busybox has the `[` symlinked to err.. busybox, can you tell me where you got the script from? It might need to be "slightly altered" to work within Android?

Comment: It's from within the app. It can be altered, but is supposed to work straight off the bat. I have never installed busybox. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to see the script ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so... I'll edit it into the question if I can get hold of it

Answer (score -2):

You must install busybox on your device. And you need a kernel with loopdevice support. I use a 2.6.35.7 Kernel and I can run Debian. You may have a ARMv6 CPU Then Ubuntu doesn't work.

Comment: This is rather vague. How would busybox help exactly? How would the OP use it to solve the problem? (As a side note, please [don't sign your posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed))